# Are graphic capabilities included in CPU used in common servers (web + thinclient)?

Tags: virtualization, performance, intel

I'm trying to decide between [these two Intel processors](http://ark.intel.com/compare/63698,52272)

The first of them has no graphic support in core.

I know that this type of graphic "cards" can be used to execute code from common (non-graphic) apps, but I don't know if the applications I'm going to install make use of this processor characteristic.

I'm going to use the server for:

- Ubuntu-KVM Hypervisor whith VMs used for

  - NComputing thinclient server (like a X desktop server (3D support is not needed)). Windows7 and Ubuntu guests
  - Database (postgres/mysql)
  - WebServer (python/php/ruby)

Does the integrated graphic support help to improve performance on these applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That processor only support OpenCL 1.1, and has 12 execution units. Compare that with the AMD A10-5800K with OpenCL 1.2 and 384 execution units. Intel's graphics are notoriously unimpressive.

It's highly unlikely any of your software will have the drivers or OpenCL capabilities to use the graphics "card" in that processor anyway. It's very uncommon to see software use GPGPUs unless they're doing extreme number crunching; like breaking encryption, graphical rendering, or data mining.